# Why does array created with 'new' become set to NULL?

Tags: c++, memory, null, allocation

I have something like this: A class with a member function which allocates some memory. Why on exit of the function, does the pointer become set to point at NULL?

```
class A
{

private:
    int* memoryblock;
public:
    void assignsome(int n);

};

void A::assignsome(int n)
{
    memoryblock = new int[n]; // At this point, debugger suggests memoryblock is not pointing to null.
}
// On exit of this function, memoryblock points to null!
```

On request: Here is the full breakdown:

```
int FileHandler::PerValueMemoryBlockRead(char* delimarray, unsigned int sizeofarray)
{
// File Opened and mValues_n calculated.
    mValues = new int[mValues_n + 1];
    mValuesAllocated = true;

// Assignment of the contents of mValues is done.

    mValues[next_value_pos] = 0x0; // Last int set to zero. /// next_value_pos is an int which is incremented. (Code Removed because there is no point showing it.)
    return 0;

}

void FileHandler::SerialPrint()
{
    if(mValuesAllocated){
        std::cout << "Address:" << mValues << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Size=" << mValues_n << "B" << std::endl;
        for(ull pr = 0; pr < mValues_n; pr ++){
            std::cout << (int)mValues[pr] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Nothing to print. 'PerValueMemoryBlockRead' has not yet been called." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Then inside main:

```
    if((!datahandle.PerValueMemoryBlockRead(delimarray, 3))
    && (!converthandle.PerValueMemoryBlockRead(delimarray, 3))
    && dataoutput.is_open()){

        dataoutput.seekp(0, std::ios::beg);

        // Code
        converthandle.SerialPrint(); // SEG FAULT
        datahandle.SerialPrint(); // SEG FAULT
        // End Code
```

Comment: `memoryblock` will still be pointing at the array of `int`s. Is this your real code?

Comment: _How_ do you check that the block is `NULL`?

Comment: That will **NEVER** happen (if new does not work it throws). But when you exit the method. But what may be happening is that the debugger will not know which instance of A you want to print the member `memoryblock` from.

Comment: The function continues, and the pointer is set to NULL after the function does: `return 0`

Comment: If I print the value of `memoryblock` the output is '0'

Comment: Both instances of the class A do the same.

Comment: Does your program observe that pointer as null? Are you debugging a release build?

Comment: The program works correctly until the function returns. Then the memory block points to zero. It will cout the contents of the memory before returning zero as expected. Once another function is called to do the printing again, it is already pointing to NULL.

Comment: What about the value of `a.memoryblock`? Where is `a` set?

Comment: @EdwardBird no, I mean, can you write a statement in your program that finds memoryblock equal to NULL? Or can you only see this in the debugger?

Comment: By *complete example* I meant a [sscce](http://sscce.org). I don't want to see the original code causing you problems, I want you to try and reproduce the problem in a small example. This will probably lead you to enlightenment. If nothing happens for you, post it here.

Comment: This code is full of smells. The first is: why are you reinventing `std::vector`? Where does `next_value_pos` come from? Why do you have `(int)mValues[pr]` the cast shouldn't be necessary, isn't `mValues` of type `int*`? We can trivially prove that your initial code *doesn't* have the bug you claim it does: http://rextester.com/NVGGT50567, http://ideone.com/F3EuPm

Comment: Most of all, you've removed code from paste of PerValueMemoryBlockRead: you don't show how you copy the data, which is a typical point of failure in bad code like this.

Comment: @kfsone Do you mind not trauling my decades old questions at midnight? I'm trying to sleep here - thanks. I have no clue wtf this code was supposed to do but it sure looks like a smart idea for a new project

Comment: @user3728501 didn't look at the age, it was unanswered at the top of the feed. maybe someone replied or edited.

Comment: @kfsone I think you might be right - someone made an edit but not sure what the details are. Anyways, sleep tight my sweet prince

Answer (score 0):

If you put the breakpoint there, the debugger still hasn't run the line.

Continue to the next line to see it assigned.

Comment: Done that. Result is the same

Comment: @EdwardBird if you're compiling and runing in release (with compiler optimizations) the `this` pointer is sometimes optimized to the hardware registers. This causes the class members to seem like junk. Try compiling it in debug, with no optimizations.

Comment: Yes, that is how it is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger can be a bit misleading in such cases. In fact the pointer is not NULL, debugger is simply confused and don'y know which `A` are you talking about. I suggest using debug printing when in doubt in similar cases.

Comment: Done that. Result is the same

Comment: @EdwardBird Give us a complete example. About 15 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the instance of `A` has a value `memoryblock` not equal to NULL after calling `assignsome`:

```
class A
{
private:
    int* memoryblock;
public:
    void assignsome(int n);
};

void A::assignsome(int n)
{
    memoryblock = new int[n];
}

int main () {
    A a;
    a.assignsome(5);
    return 0; // breakpoint here - a.memoryblock isn't NULL
}
```